# Iterating window size on a rolling function, appending to a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration, rolling-computation

I am trying to iterate a rolling calculation from a data frame, iterating / changing the window size each time, then appending that to a new data frame, with a new column each time.

code is as follows:

```
window_list = [39, 52, 65, 78, 91, 104]

for i in window_list: 
    window = i
    df_SP_final = pd.DataFrame(index=df_SP.index)
    df_SP_final.insert(loc=0,column=i,value=0.5*(((df_SP.pcent - df_SP.pcent.rolling(window=window,min_periods=min_periods).mean())
```

The output is a just the 104 column. Looks like the for loop is not working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You're reinitializing your `df_SP_final` each time you try a new window.
I think you meant to do:

```
window_list = [39, 52, 65, 78, 91, 104]
df_SP_final = pd.DataFrame(index=df_SP.index)

for window in window_list: 
    df_SP_final.insert(loc=0,column=i,value=0.5*(((df_SP.pcent - df_SP.pcent.rolling(window=window,min_periods=min_periods).mean())
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix!